# Including project within another project

Tags: android, reference, project

I built an app and published it for purchase in the Android Market. Now what I would like to do is release another version of it that is free. Once you install it though its going to ask you for an activation code. I have built that program seperately. I was wondering if there was a way I could include my first app into the second one (like an include statement in C# and reference?) I dont want to have to update 2 projects every time I release an update.

**UPDATE**

Ok, ive managed to set my first application as a library. Then I went into the properties of my second application and added the library to it. The src folder for the first application showed up in the second one but Im seeing that the resources were not imported. Is there an easier way of doing this or do I have to manually copy over all my layouts, values and drawables as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this doc on [managing projects](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html). You should probably separate all the common functionality out into a common library project.